# Unity server build (headless) native texture pointer returns 0

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, textures, render-to-texture

When I run the following code inside a Unity Editor, or if I build and run it (not in headless mode) `GetNativeTexturePtr()` returns a value `>0` for the texture id, etc.

However, when building the app having a **Server Build** option enabled `GetNativeTexturePtr()` always returns `0`. Even when `IsCreated()` returns true.

Any ideas what is happening here?

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private RenderTexture m_RenderTexture;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        m_RenderTexture = new RenderTexture(256, 256, 24, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
        m_RenderTexture.Create();
        if (!m_RenderTexture.IsCreated())
        {
            Debug.LogError("RenderTexture could not be created");
        }
        Debug.Log("texture id = " + m_RenderTexture.GetNativeTexturePtr().ToString());
    }
}
```

Unity version 2019.1.9f1

Answer (score -1):

From Unity documentation on [GetNativeTexturePtr article](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture.GetNativeTexturePtr.html):

> On Direct3D-like devices this returns a pointer to the base texture
>   type (IDirect3DBaseTexture9 on D3D9, ID3D11Resource on D3D11,
>   ID3D12Resource on D3D12). On OpenGL-like devices the GL texture "name"
>   is returned; cast the pointer to integer type to get it. On Metal, the
>   id pointer is returned. **On platforms that do not support
>   native code plugins, this function always returns NULL.**

and Unity Manual on [Server/Headless build](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html):

> Enable this checkbox to build the Player for server use and **with no
>   visual elements (headless)** without the need for any command line
>   options. [...]

A Server/Headless build will not use the graphic API, thus calling `GetNativeTexture` will always return `NULL`.

Comment: Hi. Regarding the first statement: On my platform native code plugins are supported. And I can use my native code inside the server build. So I guess this is something different.

Comment: Hmm. So since in the headless mode my Renderer is a `Null device` this is probably why the `GetNativeTexturePtr` returns 0. But is it possible to run the server build where the Renderer is not a `Null device`?

Comment: @DimitriPodborski do you run the headless build on Linux or Windows ? Linux builds communicates with Xorg for graphical updates, headless mode disable all communication between the game and Xorg at the moment (read harpej answer here: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/issues/1050#issuecomment-459614476), it is specified in Unity ML-agents project documentation (https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/master/docs/Using-Docker.md). harpej's answer hint that Xorg dependency may be removed in the future. For now, you have to uncheck "Headless" to use the GPU.

Comment: Im on macOS and win10. Same problem accros all platforms.

Comment: Your best bet is to build the game without "headless" option then run the game with command line argument `-batchmode` (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html). I presume headless option will force the `-nographics` option on your builds.